# Returning boolean values in sparql

Tags: boolean, sparql

From the rdf file, I need to return true for the person if their age is even, false if their age is odd. I wrote the query to display persons with even age, but need to modify to display the results in boolean values.

```
select * where { ?x h:age ?age . 
         filter(    strends(?age, 0) || strends(?age, 2) || strends(?age, 4) || strends(?age, 6) || strends(?age, 8)  )
}
```

Comment: 1. I don't understand why the age in your data is a string value 2. use SPARQL `BIND` keyword: `BIND(if(strends(?age, 0) || strends(?age, 2) || strends(?age, 4) || strends(?age, 6) || strends(?age, 8), "true"^^xsd:boolean, "false"^^xsd:boolean ) as ?even)`

Comment: @vishnuprashanth, there exists [`ASK`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#ask).

Comment: @StanislavKralin From what I understand is that he want's to have an additional "column" that prints true resp. false depending on the age.

Comment: @AKSW, you are right, excuse me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an even test is `?X/2 =  FLOOR(?X/2)`.

So if `?age` has a numeric datatype:

```
where { ?x h:age ?age . 
        BIND( (?age/2 =  FLOOR(?age/2)) AS ?isEven)
       }
```

will add `?isEven` as true/false.

If `?age` is a string, then replace `?age` with `xsd:integer(?age)`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar case. I needed to return in the results true/false if the optional relationship exists.

```
SELECT ?c ?hasNarrowMatch
WHERE {
?c a skos:Concept.
OPTIONAL {?c skos:narrowMatch ?nm}
BIND (exists{?c skos:narrowMatch ?nm} AS ?y)
BIND (IF(?y, "true", "false") AS ?hasNarrowMatch)
}
```

The results will look like this:

```
+-----+----------------+
|  c  | hasNarrowMatch |
+-----+----------------+
| c1  | true           |
| c2  | false          |
| c3  | true           |
+-----+----------------+
```

Comment: Exactly the problem I wanted to solve. Thanks!